# access fields from log using ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash, elastic-stack

What I am trying to do is pass my grok fields in some way or another to an external ruby filter-script and set based on these fields specific tags. The problem is that I can only get the whole log message with the event API.

My question is: is it possible to access fields from the already processed log message in the ruby filter or do I have to parse the whole message myself, which would not be optimal because every log message is processed twice? Alternatively I could completely dump the grok filter and do everything myself in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
You can get read-only access to any field using [Event API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html#_event_api)

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => 'event.get("foo" )'
  }
}
```

field can also be a nested field reference such as `[field][bar]`.

```
event.get("[foo][bar]")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My error actually was that "event.get("foo")" did not return a string, which I thought. And I havn't worked with Ruby before so I didn't read that from the error message.

Comment: you can try splitting the result based on what it is,
`event.get("foo" ).split(',')`